# Apply formula with respect to column number across multiple csv files

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have found mean of all columns separately for 10 csv files. Now I have to compare avg value of all columns and then find minimum avg value with respect to column number.
I have 10 csv files, 80 columns in each file.

```
myfunction<-function(filename)
{
dat<-read.csv(file=filename,header=FALSE)
avg_per_column<-apply(dat,2,mean)
min_average_value<-min(avg_per_column)
```

This is giving me minimum across all columns. I want avg minimum for column 2 across all files

```
dev.new(plot(min_average_value))
}
```

##how to apply find min for each column across all files? Example - find minimum of File1-column2 average vs File2-column2 average vs File3-column2 average and so on.** Have to find minimum across all columns and plot it.

```
filelist <-list.files(pattern="myfilename",full.names=TRUE)

for (i in filelist)    
{
  dev.new(myfunction(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=runif(10),b=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(15),b=runif(15))
lists <- list(df1,df2)
```

Calculation of `mean` over all the files

```
m <- matrix(rapply(lists,mean),byrow = TRUE,ncol = ncol(df1))
colnames(m)=colnames(df1)
```

So, `minimum` of `average`s of each column over all the files

```
apply(m,2,min)
```

Comment: Haven't worked with data frame commands yet, so looking into what you've mentioned. Have to figure out how to read the csv's into this.Thank you.

Comment: what arguments will I have to use instead of rapply(lists,mean).

Comment: your code is good, no errors. I have to get my data into it using a for loop.

Comment: Yes, it does. Should I go for rapply(filelist,avg_per_column)

Comment: No. Don't use your code. Use this to read all of them `filelist <- lapply(list.files(pattern="myfilename",full.names = TRUE),read.csv)`